# Use wildcard to capture different datasets in Snakemake

Tags: wildcard, snakemake

I would like to use wildcards in Snakemake in a very simple way to start a script for two datasets. Unfortunately, I cannot find the proper way of doing it.

My data folder contains three files: *gene_list.txt*, *expression_JGI.txt*, *expression_UBC.txt*.

Here is what my snakefile looks like:

```
rule extract:
    input:
        genes="data/gene_list.txt",
        expression="data/expression_{dataset}.txt"
    output:
        "data/expression_{dataset}_subset.txt"
    shell:
        "bash scripts/extract.sh {input.genes} {input.expression} {output}"
```

When I use `snakemake -c1 extract` I get the following error message:

> Building DAG of jobs...
> WorkflowError:
> Target rules may not contain wildcards. Please specify concrete files or a rule without wildcards at the command line, or have a rule without wildcards at the very top of your workflow (e.g. the typical "rule all" which just collects all results you want to generate in the end).

I tried adding a `rule all` at the beginning of the snakefile with the desired result files as input without success:

```
rule all:
    input:
        "data/expression_JGI_subset.txt",
        "data/expression_UBC_subset.txt"
```

I also tried with *expand*:

```
DATASETS = ["JGI", "UBC"]

rule all:
    input:
        expand("data/expression_{dataset}_subset.txt", dataset=DATASETS)
```

But I get the same error message.

The script works fine when I use it outside Snakemake.

How can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `snakemake -c1 extract` you ask snakemake to execute only rule `extract` and its dependencies, if any. However, because `extract` contains wildcards snakemake doesn't know what to replace them with. (Note that rule `all` is not a dependency of `extract`).

So either execute `snakemake -c1` to run the whole pipeline or specify the concrete files you want to generate, e.g.:

```
snakemake -c1 -- data/expression_JGI_subset.txt data/expression_UBC_subset.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it works perfectly. What does the "--" mean in the snakemake command line though?

Comment: `--` indicates that everything after it is positional arguments. In the example above is not necessary. `--` is common syntax for many command-line programs. For example, if you want to `grep` the pattern `-foo` in file test.txt you need to use `grep -- '-foo' test.txt` to tell grep that `-foo` is not an optional argument. If you omit `--` you get the error `grep: oo: No such file or directory`